# MonetDB stored procedure return table

Tags: stored-procedures, monetdb

From MonetDB-user's:

> ***You cannot use an ordinary select query in a procedure.***  You can change
>   the contents of tables or set variables, but you cannot use a query like
>   this.  Remember, with such a query, there is a result, and where should
>   the result go?

What's the correct way on MonetDB to create kind of:

```
CREATE XXXX
BEGIN
   SELECT * FROM table;
END
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems more like a job for a `VIEW`, e.g.

```
CREATE VIEW XXXX AS SELECT * FROM table;

SELECT * FROM XXXX;
```

If you want to create a function, you can do this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION XXXX() 
RETURNS TABLE (name string)
RETURN TABLE (SELECT name from tables);

SELECT * FROM XXXX();
```

Note that in the second case, you need to specify the schema of the returned table in the function definition.